# How to set typescript type for prop value that takes in unique union types in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

trying to set a type for a prop value but not quite sure how to go about doing so, since the type are string unions that vary depending on where the React Component is being used.

This is my typescript interface.

```
interface IProps {
  tabs: {
    label: string;
    tabId: string;
  }[];
 onClick: (tabId: string) => void;
}
```

The React component is used in several different places in my application. Here are two different examples of this.

```
const toggleTabs = (type: 'share' | 'home' | 'settings' ) => setActiveTab(type);
<Tabs  onClick={toggleTabs} />
```

2nd example

```
const toggleTabs = (type: 'history' | 'shopping' ) => setActiveTab(type);
<Tabs  onClick={toggleTabs} />
```

However, this gives me the following error, since typescript string type does not equal the string union type above.

`Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"history" | "shopping"`

Since I use different string unions for each implementation, I'm not sure what type to set it as.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using a generic parameter:

```
interface IProps<Tabs extends string> {
  tabs: {
    label: string;
    tabId: string;
  }[];
  onClick: (tabId: Tabs) => void;
}
```

And where you'd normally use `IProps`, you add the parameter in:

```
function Tabs<T extends string>(props: IProps<T>) {
```

Then whenever you use the component, the type will be automatically inferred:

```
<Tabs tabs={[]} onClick={(tab: "history" | "shopping") => tab} />
//  ^ Tabs<"history" | "shopping">
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wjQVkW)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would I go about adding the parameter if my function is an arrow function like so

```const Tabs: React.FC<IProps> = ({ tabs, onClick}) => {```

Comment: Don't have an environment to confirm but I think it's `const Tabs: React.FC<IProps<string>> = <T extends string>({ ... }: IProps<T>) => {`